# Expand macro in options list for environment

Tags: macros, environments, options

I am trying to define some options for an environment using a macro.

```tex
\usepackage{tabularray}

....

% previous parameter definition, does not scale
\def\cellax{1}
\def\cellay{2}
\def\cellaw{4}

\def\cellbx{2}
\def\cellby{3}
\def\cellbw{5}

% want to use a macro taking arguments
\newcommand{\newcell}[3]{
    hline{#2-{#2+1}}={#1-{#1 + #3 - 1}}{solid},
    vline{#1,#1+#3}={#2}{solid},
    cell{#2}{#1}={c=#3}{c},
}
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \ttfamily
    \centering
    $\begin{tblr}{
        hline{1}={1-Z}{solid},
        hline{2}={1-Z}{solid},
        vline{1}={1}{solid},
        vline{2-11}={1}{dashed},
        %
        hline{\cellay-{\cellay+1}}={\cellax-{\cellax + \cellaw - 1}}{solid},
        vline{\cellax,\cellax+\cellaw}={\cellay}{solid},
        cell{\cellay}{\cellax}={c=\cellaw}{c},
        %
        hline{\cellby-{\cellby+1}}={\cellbx-{\cellbx + \cellbw - 1}}{solid},
        vline{\cellbx,\cellbx+\cellbw}={\cellby}{solid},
        cell{\cellby}{\cellbx}={c=\cellbw}{c},
        % Want to use it here ....
        \newcell{4, 4, 4},
        %
        hspan = even,
    }
    x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4&x_5&x_6&x_7&x_8&x_9&x_{10}&\ldots\\
    n_1&\\
    &n_2  \\ 
    &&n_3  \\ 
    &&&&\ddots  \\ 
    \end{tblr}$
\end{table}
```

Essentially I am trying to replace the definitions using `\cellax` ("cell A, x coordinate"), `\cellbx`, etc. with a macro taking 3 arguments and expanding to the definition of a few `hline`s and `vline`s and a `cell`. These are all options for the `tblr` environment from the `tabularray` package, as far as I am aware.

This code produces the error "You can't use macro parameter character # in horizontal mode" in the `newcommand`, but even when I insert concrete values into the macro definition it doesn't seem to work. No new cell is created.

[image]

1. how do I correctly expand a macro in the options of an environment?
2. how do I use arguments in a macro expanding to a list of options?

Comment: Not the issue at its core but: In TeX, a macro defined as `\newcommand\foo[3]{<stuff>}` should be used as `\foo{a}{b}{c}`, not as `\foo{a, b, c}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your key=value contents can be subject to full expansion you could use `\expanded` to expand it before the `tblr`-environment reads it. You should then protect the `\begin` from expanding (using either `\noexpand` as in the code below, or `\unexpanded{<stuff>}` with `<stuff>` replaced with whatever shouldn't expand further).

As already pointed out in my comment, arguments in TeX are separate sets of braces, so it would be `\newcell{4}{4}{4}` instead of `\newcell{4, 4, 4}`. Additionally the number of arguments for `\newcommand` is given in brackets, not braces, as that's an optional argument: `\newcommand{\newcell}[3]{<replacement text>}`.

With these things applied your code becomes the following:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{tabularray}

% previous parameter definition, does not scale
\def\cellax{1}
\def\cellay{2}
\def\cellaw{4}

\def\cellbx{2}
\def\cellby{3}
\def\cellbw{5}

% want to use a macro taking arguments
\newcommand{\newcell}[3]{
    hline{#2-{#2+1}}={#1-{#1 + #3 - 1}}{solid},
    vline{#1,#1+#3}={#2}{solid},
    cell{#2}{#1}={c=#3}{c},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \ttfamily
    \centering
    $\expanded{\noexpand\begin{tblr}{
        hline{1}={1-Z}{solid},
        hline{2}={1-Z}{solid},
        vline{1}={1}{solid},
        vline{2-11}={1}{dashed},
        %
        hline{\cellay-{\cellay+1}}={\cellax-{\cellax + \cellaw - 1}}{solid},
        vline{\cellax,\cellax+\cellaw}={\cellay}{solid},
        cell{\cellay}{\cellax}={c=\cellaw}{c},
        %
        hline{\cellby-{\cellby+1}}={\cellbx-{\cellbx + \cellbw - 1}}{solid},
        vline{\cellbx,\cellbx+\cellbw}={\cellby}{solid},
        cell{\cellby}{\cellbx}={c=\cellbw}{c},
        % Want to use it here ....
        \newcell{4}{4}{4},
        %
        hspan = even,
    }}
    x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4&x_5&x_6&x_7&x_8&x_9&x_{10}&\ldots\\
    n_1&\\
    &n_2  \\ 
    &&n_3  \\ 
    &&&&\ddots  \\ 
    \end{tblr}$
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

An alternative that gives more control could be to use `expkv`<sup>1</sup> and its key=value-expansion syntax. In the following the `V:`  in front of `\newcell` tells `expkv` to expand the following once (if it had a `=` it'd expand the value instead of the key). Everything else is forwarded untouched (or at least almost untouched, one set of outer braces around a key-name would be stripped -- something not present in your MWE).

To simplify the job of wrapping your key-list in `expkv` just for the expansion mechanism I wrote a short helper macro `\keyexpander`. If you need explanations for it just ask.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{expkv-cs}

\newcommand*\keyexpander{\ekvoptarg\keyexpanderKV{}}
\ekvcSplitAndForward\keyexpanderKV\keyexpanderDO
  {
     pre = {}
    ,post = {}
    ,keyProc  = \keyexpanderKEY
    ,pairProc = \keyexpanderPAIR
  }
\ekvcSecondaryKeys\keyexpanderKV
  {
     nmeta oarg = { pre = [, post = ] }
    ,nmeta brace-keys =
      { keyProc = \keyexpanderKEYBR, pairProc = \keyexpanderPAIRBR }
    ,nmeta plain-keys =
      { keyProc = \keyexpanderKEY, pairProc = \keyexpanderPAIR }
  }
\newcommand\keyexpanderDO[6]
  {%
    \expanded
      {%
        \unexpanded{#5#1}%
        {%
          \IfBlankF{#6}
            {%
              \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
                {%
                  \expandafter\keyexpanderCOMMA\expanded
                    {\expanded{\ekvparse{#3}{#4}{#6}}}%
                }%
            }%
        }%
      }%
    #2%
  }
\def\keyexpanderCOMMA, {}
\newcommand\keyexpanderKEY[1]{, \unexpanded{#1}}
\newcommand\keyexpanderPAIR[2]{, \unexpanded{#1}= {\unexpanded{#2}}}
\newcommand\keyexpanderKEYBR[1]{, {\unexpanded{#1}}}
\newcommand\keyexpanderPAIRBR[2]{, {\unexpanded{#1}}= {\unexpanded{#2}}}

% previous parameter definition, does not scale
\def\cellax{1}
\def\cellay{2}
\def\cellaw{4}

\def\cellbx{2}
\def\cellby{3}
\def\cellbw{5}

% want to use a macro taking arguments
\newcommand{\newcell}[3]{
    hline{#2-{#2+1}}={#1-{#1 + #3 - 1}}{solid},
    vline{#1,#1+#3}={#2}{solid},
    cell{#2}{#1}={c=#3}{c},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \ttfamily
    \centering
    $\keyexpander{\begin{tblr}}{
        hline{1}={1-Z}{solid},
        hline{2}={1-Z}{solid},
        vline{1}={1}{solid},
        vline{2-11}={1}{dashed},
        %
        hline{\cellay-{\cellay+1}}={\cellax-{\cellax + \cellaw - 1}}{solid},
        vline{\cellax,\cellax+\cellaw}={\cellay}{solid},
        cell{\cellay}{\cellax}={c=\cellaw}{c},
        %
        hline{\cellby-{\cellby+1}}={\cellbx-{\cellbx + \cellbw - 1}}{solid},
        vline{\cellbx,\cellbx+\cellbw}={\cellby}{solid},
        cell{\cellby}{\cellbx}={c=\cellbw}{c},
        % Want to use it here ....
        V: \newcell{4}{4}{4},
        %
        hspan = even,
      }
    x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4&x_5&x_6&x_7&x_8&x_9&x_{10}&\ldots\\
    n_1&\\
    &n_2  \\ 
    &&n_3  \\ 
    &&&&\ddots  \\ 
    \end{tblr}$
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output like above.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Disclaimer: I'm the author of `expkv`.</sub>

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much.. Unfortunately it is difficult to find such tricks by simply googling. Hopefully this helps others in the future.

Comment: @stimulate I have yet another (more complicated) approach... I'll edit (for your use case, at least as given in the question, this first code should suffice, the other variant gives more control).

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on why the second example is more flexible or do you have an example how to use it?

Comment: @stimulate in the first code block `\cellax` etc. are expanded as well. If their state would change during the key=value processing that wouldn't be reflected later on. Using `expkv` you get a notation to selectively expand single keys without affecting anything else. For instance `o: ` expands once, `e: ` expands fully in `\expanded`, `V: ` expands once and reinserts the list as additional key=value input.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you mean, though I think I am not deep enough in Latex and Macro expansion yet to imagine all of the possible use cases.. your first answer completely suffices for now :)

Answer (score 1):

The same diagram can be achieved using TeX primitives only. Creating such macros is much more fun.

```
\newdimen\bw  \bw=1.8em

\def\dashrule{\lower4pt\vbox to15pt{%
   \cleaders\vbox{\kern.5pt\hrule height2pt width.4pt\kern.5pt}\vfil}%
}
\def\xcells#1{\ifx\relax#1\else 
   \hbox to\bw{\hfil$x_{#1}$\hfil \dashrule}%
   \expandafter\xcells\fi
}
\def\boxik#1#2#3{
   \moveright#1\bw\vbox{\kern-.4pt
      \hrule
      \hbox to#2\bw{\vrule height 11pt depth4pt \hfil$#3$\hfil\vrule}
      \hrule
   }
}

\vbox{\offinterlineskip
   \hrule
   \hbox{\vrule\kern-.4pt \xcells 123456789{10}\relax \kern2pt\dots\kern2pt}
   \hrule
   \boxik 0 4 {n_1}
   \boxik 1 5 {n_2}
   \boxik 2 5 {n_3}
   \moveright 4.5\bw\hbox{$\ddots$}
}
```